# Open a link in a new tab if the browser supports it

Tags: jquery, html

This might be pretty silly, but I am a newb.

This is the classic link I use:

```
<a href="new.php" target="_blank">New Link</a>
```

1. Latest Mozilla version opens the link in a new tab, while IE opens it in a new window.
2. Read somewhere that the target `_blank` will be deprecated.

What can I use (either HTML, jQuery or CSS) in order to make my links open **firstly in a new tab** and if the **browser does not support this**, or even does not have tabs function, **open the link in a new window**?

Comment: I don´t think you can control how/where the browser open new windows as it´s a browser setting for the user to decide over.

Comment: Which Internet Explorer have you got? Cause my IE9 opens a _blank link in a new tab (even in compatibility modes)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can completely control whether a browser opens a new window or tab. At least not on any browser on any platform and with any settings. The browser "decides" it for you.

To replace the target attribute, you could use JS. If it's not enabled, the link at least still works.

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" 
onclick="window.open(this.href); return false;" 
onkeypress="window.open(this.href); return false;">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You simply instruct the browser to open a new window, and then the browser decides (based on the user's preferences) whether to open it in a new window or new tab.

Comment: Nope. The browser will ultimately decide whether to open it in a tab or window.

Comment: Really? I tried without the JS code and the browser didn't open a new tab. I inserted the JS code and the browser opened the link in a new tab. It worked for me...

Comment: @DiAlex - please read my response more carefully. We're talking about whether you can force a browser to open a new tab vs. window using your code. You can't. The browser decides based on user preferences. If you change your browser's preferences to open new windows rather then new tabs, then new windows will be opened. My response is exactly the same as mat's, just without the code.

Comment: Actually, maybe it's the original post you need to read more clearly. The OP wants to "make my links open firstly in a new tab and if the browser does not support this, or even does not have tabs function, open the link in a new window". All I said is you can't decide programmatically whether the browser should open the page in a new tab or a new window.